# A preposition for "act"

Tags: phrase-request

> the second rule **acts in** the context provided by the first rule

Is it the correct use of "act"?

I mean the second rule applies on something in the context provided by the first rule.

Answer (score 1):

*In* is right, if you mean *inside of*.

For *to act*, the only "special" preposition that changes the meaning is "on"--*to act on X* means "to do an activity that is indicated by X" or "to respond appropriately with X."

Comment: “Act on X” can either mean a response to X (“I acted on incorrect information”) or something that affects X (“a force acts on an object”).